# How can I convert dist.js to Json

Tags: javascript, json

This is my dist.js file:

```
var dist = [
    ['town1', [], []],
    ['town2', [271], ['10h30m']],
    ['town3', [93,178], ['3h26m','7h04m']],
    ['town4', [342,71,245], ['13h24m','2h30m','9h29m']],
    ...
```

what is the format for putting this into a json?  (with the town the distance and the time)
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Can you be a little more specific . The array you list is in javascript. JSON is just Javascript Object Notation. It's not clear exactly what you want to do.

Comment: Sorry, what I am trying to achieve is using two spinners (one for "From Location" and the other one "Final Destination") in android to calculate the distance between the towns and the time it would take.  I have read countless forums and all suggest that it should be in a JSON Array.  But I don't know how do this.

Comment: [`JSON.stringify(dist)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) anyone?

Comment: That's a winner... Should convert the array to a string object containing the JSON.

Comment: Thanks but can i give you my code for the two spinners and what I then need to do from there? Or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Here is the link to a previousely question I asked about this similar topic with my code, is this correct? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962831/can-i-use-two-spinners-to-retrieve-data-from-a-javasript-file-that-i-have-named/12970625#12970625

Comment: Anyone? I am really desperate to solve this problem I am having :-(

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you wanted:

```
var dist = [[
    "town1", 
    [271],
    ['10h30m']
],[
    "town2",
    ...
]];
var output = JSON.stringify(dist);  //"ouptput" is containing
                                    //your array in JSON format
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/zddME/

Comment: How do i add that to my code?  after spinner.setAdapter(adapter)?  here is a link to the qeustion I asked yesterday. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962831/can-i-use-two-spinners-to-retrieve-data-from-a-javasript-file-that-i-have-named/12970625#12970625

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for an array in JSON is: `[ item, item, item ]`

You need to strip the `var dist =` and probably a traling `;`.

I don't know Java but in JavaScript, the code for doing so would be similar to this:

```
var json = 'var dist = [ .... ];'; // the file's contents

json = json.substring(11);
json = json.replace(/;\s+$/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

From the link you provided to your previous question, it seems you are including a file in your android project that contains some JavaScript. This JavaScript has information you want use in your Java (with the spinners).

Your code in your other question shows that you have read in the .js file and tried to turn it into a JSONArray. I imagine this is giving you a JSON Exception. If you delete the 'var dist = ' and the semicolon at the end, the file would contain JSON. You can verify something is valid JSON as JSONLint.com

If you are not actually evaluating the JavaScript, I suggest you rename you file to .json instead of .js--this will help avoid confusion.

Comment: I have posted an update could you please have a look at it and tell me what i am doing wrong?